# Change color of placeholder text on keyboard in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift

In iOS 10, if you select an input with a placeholder, the placeholder text will show on the keyboard like so:

[image]

The text color however is very light and difficult to read.

Is there a way to change this color?

Answer (score 3):

There is!

Connect your text field to your viewController, then assign it a color programmatically.

```
myTextField.setPlaceholderColor(UIColor.black)
```

Comment: @Scott Haley Is there anything wrong with this answer? I tested it and it worked...

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing, but that method doesn't seem to be available. Maybe different version of swift? I'm using swift3

Comment: @ScottHaley I'm in swift 3, also... is this not a UITextField?

Answer (score 0):

This will make it easy to control the place holder color inside of the storyboard

```
@IBInspectable var placeHolderColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        let rawString = attributedPlaceholder?.string != nil ? attributedPlaceholder!.string : ""
        let str = NSAttributedString(string: rawString, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: placeHolderColor!])
        attributedPlaceholder = str
    }
}
```